# Convertir la Diferencia de dos fechas en un entero

Tags: php

Quiero convertir la diferencia entre dos fechas en un entero, este es el código que me saca la diferencia pero me genera un string y requiero un entero para utilizar ese valor en operaciones aritméticas gracias

```
<?php
 $datetime1 = date_create('2017-05-26');
 $datetime2 = date_create('2018-05-22');
 $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
 echo $interval->format('%r%a');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Respecto a tu duda, de acuerdo a la documentación en PHP podrías hacer un **"cast"** ó **manipulación de tipos**, intenta con esto:

```
<?php  $diasInt = (int) $interval->format("%r%a");
       var_dump ($diasInt); //para verificar el tipo de la variable
       echo $diasInt;        
?>
```

Te dejo el enlace a la documentación oficial, contiene varios ejemplos: http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php.

Anexo imágen de que el código es funcional y cumple con tu duda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Saludos.*

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es una función **php** que te parsea `string` a `int`, me alegra comunicarte que algo así existe y es tal que así:

**PHP**

```
 intval( mixed $diferenciaFechas [, int $base = 10 ])
```

Lo que hay entre corchetes es opcional, solo es para definir en qué base numérica está el número que introduces

(p.ej: si pasas un número binario `base = 2`, si fuese **hexadecimal**, 16), por defecto viene en base 10 que es el sistema numérico habitual.

Espero que te sea de ayuda :), si es así siempre ayuda un +1 :D

Answer (score 0):

Alfonso, ese entero **ya existe en tu objeto**. Sólo tienes que obtener el valor dentro del objeto si es lo que te interesa. Te ahorras así el tener que aplicar formatos de salida para luego reconvertir de nuevo.

Si haces un `var_dump($interval)` podrás ver que en efecto tu objeto tiene una propiedad `days`, la cual es del tipo `int`, o sea, el dato y tipo que necesitas:

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(11)
  ["d"]=>
  int(26)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(361)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Eso significa que tú puedes obtener el valor de esa propiedad tal cual a través de tu objeto, que para eso lo tienes:

```
$intDiff=$interval->days;
```

Como esta, puedes obtener cualquiera de las otras propiedades que necesites, sin tener que recurrir a otro tipo de manipulaciones. Esa es una de las grandes ventajas de trabajar con objetos.

**Prueba:**

Si probamos de qué tipo es la variable que acabamos de crear, tomándola del objeto directamente:

```
var_dump($intDiff);
```

**Salida:**

Veremos que es una variable del tipo `int`. O sea, justo lo que buscas.

```
int(361)
```

Haciendo esto te ahorras dos pasos:

1. Tener que aplicar formato: `$strDiff= $interval->format('%r%a');`
2. Para luego tener que convertirlo a entero.